# Limit array size Couchbase update query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

i have got a couchbase n1ql update query:

```
UPDATE `store` document USE KEYS "test" 
SET document = ARRAY_APPEND(ARRAY_REMOVE(document, "c"), "c")
```

this update will remove all occurences of the given "c" from the document and is then appending it to the end.

now i also want to limit the resulting array to a specific length, so the result never exeeds something like 50 array elements or so

since array slicing wont give a propper result, when the length of the array is less than the given slice, there is some more logic required.

i have tried the following:

```
UPDATE `store` document USE KEYS "test" 
LET temp = ARRAY_APPEND(ARRAY_REMOVE(document, "c"), "c")
SET document = temp[-least(ARRAY_LENGTH(temp), 50):]
```

which fails, because "LET" is not part of the UPDATE syntax

is there any way to achieve limiting the stored array in size by using a single update statement?

EDIT:
with the selected answer and an additional case for new documents, i came up with this final solution:

```
MERGE INTO `store` document
USING (SELECT NULL) s ON KEY "test_x"
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET document = ARRAY_REVERSE(
        ARRAY v FOR i:v IN ARRAY_REVERSE(
            ARRAY_APPEND(ARRAY_REMOVE(document, "i"), "i")
        ) WHEN i < 3 END
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ["i"]
RETURNING *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the length of an array using an indexed ARRAY operator, like this:

```
select array v for i:v in ["a", "b", "c", "d"]  when i < 2 end
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "$1": [
      "a",
      "b"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: this was surprisingly helpful.
any ideas other than reversing the array twice, to get the "last x" elements instead of the "first x"?

Comment: `UPDATE \`store\` document USE KEYS "test" 
SET document = ARRAY_REVERSE(ARRAY v FOR i:v IN ARRAY_REVERSE(ARRAY_APPEND(ARRAY_REMOVE(document, "g"), "g")) WHEN i < 3 END)`
this is what i came up with. it seems to work, but i am not so happy about the reversal

Comment: There is an ARRAY_LENGTH() function. You should be able to use something like WHEN i >ARRAY_LENGTH(...)-50, with some adjustments for edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subquery expressions that are more flexible (like remove based on logical fields of objects) etc. If you need 50 elements give 49 because you are adding one more at the end.

```
UPDATE `store` AS document
USE KEYS "test"
SET document = ARRAY_APPEND((SELECT RAW d1 FROM document AS d1 WHERE d1 != "c" OFFSET ARRAY_LENGTH(document) - 49  LIMIT 49),"c");
```

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/subqueries.html

Comment: Will try that tomorrow